# Fetch on non-active branch with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

If I'm working in Git, I can update a branch I do not currently have checked out. For instance, if I'm in a feature branch and see master is out-of-date from my `origin` remote, I can run the following to update it without checking it out first.

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

Is there some way to make this same call in LibGit2Sharp?

I see that Fetch can take a repo and a remote, but I don't quite understand the refspec concept enough to know what parameter I would need to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

For full details about refspecs, I guess you already had a look at the [official git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

As you said, you can pass an array of refspec to the `Fetch` command. So in order to do the equivalent of:

`git fetch origin master:master`

You would have to use:

```
        using (var repo = new Repository(path))
        {
            Commands.Fetch(repo, "origin",
                new string[] { "refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" },
                null, null);
        }
```